# Tensorflow keras model.predict() fails

Tags: machine-learning, tf.keras

I am doing my machine learning project in Keras.

I am using a k-fold cross-validation and later I am using the built-in model.predict().

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(w, input_dim=w, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(lw1, activation='relu'))
#model.add(layers.Dense(round(lw1/2), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="mae")

print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(f'Training for fold {fn} ...')

history = model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=epoc,batch_size=bs)

scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
```

The fitting procedure for every fold is ending fine, with mae=0.1. The model.evaluate() method gives as well reasonable error.

The problems start when I am calling the model.predict():

```
b=X[11]

print(b)

n=model.predict(np.array([b]))

print(n)
```

The prediction runs, but the result is the same for different inputs. Thinking that the problem is in poor ANN design, I tried a simple thing - putting in the same values used in fitting - the X[train] set. By logic, it should give the same difference, because the weights were set exactly for it.

This is how it looks for different inputs (v is the generated output):

```
line in x[test]
[[6.17734280e-02 4.86320246e-03 1.42857143e-01 4.39196341e-02
  2.00000000e-01 5.26184000e+02]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
line in x[test]
[[1.23547013e-01 1.94528483e-02 1.42857143e-01 8.78393456e-02
  2.00000000e-01 3.68779000e+02]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
line in x[test]
[[1.23547013e-01 1.94528483e-02 1.42857143e-01 8.78393456e-02
  2.00000000e-01 2.09692000e+02]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
line in x[test]
[[1.23547013e-01 1.94528483e-02 1.42857143e-01 8.78393456e-02
  2.00000000e-01 9.30220000e+01]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
line in x[test]
[[0.32942755 0.30746921 0.28571429 0.34921939 0.45       8.055     ]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
line in x[test]
[[0.32942755 0.30746921 0.28571429 0.34921939 0.45       4.12681   ]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
line in x[test]
[[ 0.16471299  0.0768674   0.28571429  0.17460985  0.45       65.9551    ]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
line in x[test]
[[ 0.16471299  0.0768674   0.28571429  0.17460985  0.45       34.052     ]]
v=
[[0.17459638]]
```

I strongly believe that the problem is in the model.predict(); possibly the way I give the inputs is wrong. Any other way of calling the model.predict() gives me this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 6) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 6), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_27_input'), name='dense_27_input', description="created by layer 'dense_27_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: can you at least write the `error`  output?

Comment: Just updated the post

Comment: you gotta verify your `shape`, since you created your model with a `(None, 6) shape` but you are trying to pass a `(None, ) shape`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I mentioned, I managed to solve that problem using np.array([b]). After that, the prediction result is completely incorrect